# Does any one know how I should do this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

May be this is more of a math problem, but I really need to know how to do it? can anyone help?

```
Integrate[Sin[n1 \[Pi] sp] Sin[n2 \[Pi] sp] (1/(s - sp)), {sp, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: What are `n1`, `n2` and `s`?

Comment: @zhk some indices I want to sum over later (both of them will vary from 1 to 10 for example), you can think of them as numbers. s is also a variable . I will multiply the current integral by some other terms and integrate over s.

Comment: Then `n1[Pi]` is a syntax error.

Comment: If you are pasting Mathematica source code into a post, like \\[Pi] for example, then the posting software "eats" the leading backslash. But if you manually insert an extra backslash in front of each backslash then the first one guards the second one and you will see \\[Pi]. That will keep from confusing people into thinking that you have a function n2[Pi] instead of having n2*\\[Pi]. (It is also possible to manually edit in Greek characters if that is something you think you need to do) You can also use the formatting tools during posting to put code into highlighted blocks)

Comment: @Bill, Thank you, that was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Int = Integrate[Sin[n1 π sp] Sin[n2 π sp] (1/(s - sp)), sp]

(Limit[Int, sp -> 1] - Limit[Int, sp -> 0]) // FullSimplify
```

Comment: it still gives me this error :Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

Comment: zhk's answer works fine here -- maybe try restarting Mathematica to clear unwanted/old definitions.

Comment: @zhk thank you so much, It works fine

Comment: @zhk Thank you for your answer, I am calculating this integral now:     intn1n2s = 
    Integrate[ (1/
     2 (Cos[2 n1 \[Pi] s] (CosIntegral[-2 n1 \[Pi] (-1 + s)] - 
          CosIntegral[-2 n1 \[Pi] s]) - Log[1 - s] + Log[-s] - 
       Sin[2 n1 \[Pi] s] (SinIntegral[2 n1 \[Pi] s] + 
          SinIntegral[2 n1 \[Pi] - 2 n1 \[Pi] s]))) Sin[
    n \[Pi] s] Sin[m \[Pi] s], s] , but when I apply the Limit function for s->1 it gives me ComplexInfinity. (n1,n2,n&m are numbers ), Do you have any idea how should I fix it?